# How can i add incrementing group numbers to a querset in django admin?

Tags: python, django

Right now I have:

```
fname   lname   group#
john    smith  
Mark    Tibbet
Martin  spacey
Cornel  willis
Jack    Sparrow
```

My goal is to have them grouped like this:

```
fname   lname   group#

john    smith   1 
Mark    Tibbet  1
Martin  spacey  2
Cornel  willis  2
Jack    Sparrow 3
```

So basically i want to feed in a number (say 2) and it gives them numbers in groups of twos as I am displaying  above. There are 5 people, I wanted groups of two and even though there arent enough people, it still groups them like that until a 6th person is added and the action is run again. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: you want add group number to already existing users?

Comment: yes to already existing users

Answer (score 0):

Lest define a chuncker function

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))

def assing_group_number(group,number):
    for member in group:
        member.group = number
        member.save()

users = User.objects.all()

chunk_size = 2 
group_number = 1
final_groups = []
for group_users in chunker(users, chunk_size):
    #here we are iterating over the users in groups of length = chunk size
    #and then assigning them a group_number
    assing_group_number(group_users,group_number)
    group_number += 1
```